# How to run a function after specific time then switch it off after specific time?

Tags: java, android

I need to make my picture A to be visible after 5 seconds of pressing my button then disappear  with 5 seconds, then picture B appear also for 5 seconds then disappear :
I do something like this to show what i want but i know it is wrong so how to do it in the right way ?!??

```
Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
b.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

setTimeout(function()
{
PictureA.setVisibilty(View.Visible);
PictureB.setVisibilty(View.Visible);
},5000); 
        return false;
}
});
```

---

What i want exactly :
1- after 5 seconds of pressing button b, picture A will be visible 
2- picture A will be visible just for 10 seconds then it will be invisible
3- Then picture B will be visible immediately and just for 15 seconds
4- after 15 seconds picture B will be invisible

Comment: an approach to solve this problem is using threads.

Comment: am new on android so this approach will not help me in my issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think something like this should work:

```
Handler mHandler = new Handler();
mHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable(){
    public void run(){
        PictureA.setVisibility(View.Visible);
        PictureB.setVisibilty(View.Visible);
    }
}, 5000);
```

This will execute the runnable after 5 seconds

Comment: this will make picture a and b visible after 5 seconds, but what i want to make a visible firstly for 5 seconds then make it invisible then picture b be visible for 5 seconds then make it invisible

Comment: so make 3 separate postDelayed calls, one where you set a visible after 5000ms, one where u u make a invisible and b visible after 10000ms and one where u make b invisible after 15000ms

Comment: Oh another way you could go about this is to create an AsyncTask, but they are a bit more complicated than this method... Then you could use Thread.sleep in the background thread, and then use progress updates to change your picture visibilities.

Answer (score 0):

This might work

```
Handler mHandler = new Handler();
mHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable(){
public void run(){
    PictureA.setVisibility(View.Visible);
    thread.sleep(5000);
    PictureB.setVisibilty(View.Visible);
}
}, 5000);
```

Comment: so after 5 seconds of pressing Picture A will be visible then after 5 seconds picture B will be visible , thanks also

Comment: This is probably not the approach u want, because when using a Handler, the runnable passed to postDelayed is run on the thread the Handler was created on.. So this will make your Thread sleep for 5 seconds and your app will probably be unresponsive while the Thread is sleeping